How to make a container element square and fit content
How to make flex elements square with their size defined by the element content?
Consider this example:


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <style>
            .container{
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .item{
                aspect-ratio: 1/1;
                background-color: antiquewhite;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="item">1234</div>
            <div class="item">1<br>2<br>3</div>
            <div class="item">123456</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>



The middle element is tall and narrow. I want it to be square.
The container must not necessary be a flex provided that its children have square shape.
Update: text in the snippet is used as example; the inside of the item may be some other blocks.

As Chris Coyier points out, one of the things that can break aspect-ratio is content that forces height.

@Noleli So, aspect-ratio only adjusts height to width and not vice versa?

The spec is super confusing to read, but that seems to be the effect in many cases.

Instead of manually adding <br> breaks, set the writing-mode and text-orientation.
.item-vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}

Note: This was taken from the text-orientation docs on MDN.
Here is is in action. The default behavior is just left-to-right; no extra class needed.


.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.item {
  aspect-ratio: 1/1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.item-vertical {
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  text-orientation: upright;
}
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1234</div>
  <div class="item item-vertical">123</div>
  <div class="item">123456</div>
</div>




Thank you. The content of the item may actually be anything, for example an image or a grid of rectangular shape. Sorry I didn't mention that before.
